# How to pass Cache-Control in axios headers?

Tags: reactjs

I have tested on postman and when I pass 'Cache-Control' : 'max-age=0' ,the API gives the correct response.

But When I try to pass it from the Front end side, I am getting CORS error.

Here is how I am passing -

```
export function getDuplicateDataFromCache(url) {
  return (dispatch) =>
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: `${API}cache/test/${url}`,
      data: {},
      headers: {
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {}
```

Comment: Your error is nothing to do with the headers - your API needs to allow for cross-domain requests.

Comment: Is your code incomplete or are you missing the closing } at the end?

Comment: In the project, I have allowed CORS request